# Comment traduire "in the first place" ?

Tags: traduction, vocabulaire, anglais

[Selon](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/in%20the%20first%20place) Merriam Webster, l'expression anglaise *in the first place* possède deux sens :

> 1. —used at the end of a sentence to indicate what was true or what should have been done at the beginning of a situation
> 2. —used when listing the most important parts of something or the most important reasons for something

Comment exprimer la première signification en français ? La traduction littérale *en premier lieu*, ayant à peu près le même sens que la seconde définition de *in the first place*, ne semble pas convenir.

Pour donner un exemple, je cherche à traduire des tournures comme

> You shouldn't have done it in the first place; it's too late to
> change anything.

Comment: @Alex: attention aux réponses que vous obtenez, elles ne sont pas correctes. Lisez mes remarques dans ma réponse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

J'ajoute une réponse parce que je vois de mauvaises réponses emporter l'opinion.

« in the first place » est un reproche ou un regret (ou plus rarement une simple référence) qui dénonce une phase d'activité qui a engendré une avalanche de conséquences.

Par exemple, si quelqu'un se plaint d'une facture de téléphone trop lourde, mais qu'il a souscrit à un abonnement déraisonnable dont il n'a pas l'usage, on pourrait lui reprocher qu'il n'aurait pas dû y souscrire « in the first place ».

Cela n'a rien à voir avec l'ordre d'énonciation des problèmes. Notamment écrire « d'abord, tu n'aurais pas dû souscrire à cette formule d'abonnement » peut avoir le même sens que « in the first place », ou pas. Tout dépend des conséquences et du contexte. « D'abord » veut simplement dire « premièrement ».

Et « firstly » n'est certainement pas synonyme de « in the first place ».

Same goes for « déjà », « en premier lieu », etc.

Pour vraiment traduire « in the first place » j'utiliserais plutôt les mots « départ », « origine », etc.

Par exemple « Si dès le départ tu avais acheté un meilleur forfait » est une vraie traduction de « If you bought a better plan in the first place », i.e. right from the start.

Comment: Je traduirais son exemple comme ceci: `Tu n'aurais pas dû le faire dès le départ, c'est trop tard pour changer quoi que ce soit.`

Answer (score 3):

On utilisera volontiers [`déjà`](https://cnrtl.fr/definition/d%C3%A9j%C3%A0), d'après le TLFi :

```
II.− Lang. fam., sens log.
A.− Déjà marque un degré relatif et signifie qu'un résultat partiel est acquis dès le moment considéré.
```

Ainsi, par exemple :

> *You shouldn't have done it in the first place.*
>
> **Déjà**, tu n'aurais pas dû le faire.
>
> **Pour commencer**, tu n'aurais pas dû le faire.

ou encore

> *There are many reasons why you should pick the second candidate — she has superior field experience in the first place.*
>
> Vous avez de nombreuses raisons de choisir la seconde candidate — son expérience dans le domaine, **déjà**.
>
> Vous avez de nombreuses raisons de choisir la seconde candidate, **à commencer** par son expérience dans le domaine.

NB1 : TLFi dit que **déjà** est familier dans cet usage, c'est vrai qu'on l'emploiera plutôt à l'oral qu'à l'écrit.

NB2 : attention où placer **déjà**, cela peut changer le sens du propos : comparer `déjà, tu n'aurais pas dû le faire` (tu aurais dû t'abstenir) vs. `tu n'aurais pas dû déjà le faire` (tu aurais dû attendre).

Comment: Merci de votre réponse ! Quant à une alternative plus soutenue à _déjà_, que pensez-vous de _en premier lieu_ proposée par @CharybdeBE ?

Comment: @alex sur *en premier lieu* : je n'ai jamais entendu `en premier lieu` dans ce contexte, mais c'est peut-être régional en effet (je suis en France métropolitaine, région ouest). On comprendrait tout de même l'idée, je pense

Answer (score 0):

Pour garder la forme de "premier" on peut utiliser

`En premier lieu,`

Ou `Pour commencer` (plutot oral )

Ex : `Tu n'aurais pas dû le faire en premier lieu, c'est trop tard pour changer quoi que ce soit`

Comment: Êtes-vous sûr au sujet de _en premier lieu_ ? J'avais l'impession que cette locution ne pouvait pas prendre ce sens en français.

Comment: Oui néanmoins, c'est peut être exclusif au français de Belgique (qui comporte plus de locutions traduites littéralement des langues germaniques) (source : "mon expérience en tant que natif")

Comment: Je connais l'expression *en premier lieu*... mais je suis originaire du nord de la France !